# How to hide an Enum Value in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I have a Enum class with rights.

```
public enum UserRight {
    SYSTEMMANAGEMENT, USERADMINISTRATION, ROLEADMINISTRATION, 
    STRUCTUREADMINISTRATION, DOCUMENTADMINISTRATION;
}
```

Now i want to load all my rights into a list except SYSTEMMANAGEMENT. 
I do it now like this:

```
availrightslist.addAll(Arrays.asList(UserRight.values()));
```

How can I load all rights without the SYSTEMMANAGEMENT right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just remove it after you've added all:

```
availrightslist.remove(UserRight.SYSTEMMANAGEMENT);
```

Or use some `EnumSet` *magic*:

```
Set<UserRight> rights = EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(UserRight.SYSTEMMANAGEMENT));
```

Generally if you have a `Collection` of `enum`s it is recommended to use an `EnumSet`. Because having a `UserRight` two times doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove your unwanted right.

```
Collections.addAll(availrightslist, UserRight.values())
availrightslist.remove(UserRight.SYSTEMMANAGEMENT);
```

Or you just add what you need.

```
for(UserRight right : UserRight.values()) {
    if(right != UserRight.SYSTEMMANAGEMENT)
        availrightslist.add(right);
}
```

Comment: `availrightslist.addAll(Arrays.asList(UserRight.values()))` may be simplified to `Collections.addAll(availrightslist, UserRight.values())`

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in support for hiding an enum value, you have to manually filter it out:

```
List<UserRight> okRights = Arrays.stream(UserRights.values())
    .filter(userRight -> userRight != UserRight.SYSTEMMANAGEMENT)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
availablerightslist.addall(okRights);
```

Comment: Arrays.asList() returns a fixed-size list. You can't call remove() on it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks for the correction, will update.